# Resharper is not working in Blazor web assembly application

Tags: resharper, blazor-webassembly

I need to check the performance for blazor web assembly application by using Resharper. So I have created  blazor web assembly application. After build the sample, to check the performance in Resharper by using "Run Startup Configuration Performance Profiling" option. Then, Sample is run in browser, but the resharper's performance profile window is not responding after browser is opened. Please refer the screenshot for the issue.

[Resharper's performance profile window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymU69.png)

I also tried the same sample in blazor server side application, Resharper's performance profiling tab is working.

Please give some resolution for this problem.

Comment: What .NET and ReSharper versions are you using? It's possible that ReSharper doesn't support what you want to do yet.

Answer (score 0):

dotTrace (JetBrains .NET Performance profiler) does not support profiling client-side Blazor WebAssembly application since it's not a common .NET process.